# What string format to deserialize into Map<String, String> via TypeReference with jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to test code that uses jackson to deserialize a string of key/value properties into a `Map<String, String>`. I need to find the format of the input string. I thought it was one of the following formats, but both are returning null from the objectMapper.readValue()

```
String testDeserStr = "{\n" +
                "  \"password\" : \"pwValue\",\n" +
                "  \"meterNumber\" : \"meterNumber1233445\",\n" +
                "  \"accountNumber\" : \"accountNumber6789\",\n" +
                "  \"key\" : \"keyValue\"\n" +
                "}";

String testDeserStr = "{password=pwValue, meterNumber=meterNumber1233445, accountNumber=accountNumber6789, key=keyValue}";
```

With these strings, it's trying to read them via the following:

```
final TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() { };

Map<String, String> result = objectMapper.readValue(testDeserStr, typeRef);
```

I've used jackson before to both serialize and deserialize, but haven't used this TypeReference before. What am I doing wrong? What is the format of the input string?

Comment: Second one is invalid json

Comment: Remove \n in first example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your 1st example is correct JSON.
- Your 2nd example is incorrect JSON.
- Your parsing logic **is correct**.

I just tested:

```
public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String testDeserStr = "{\n" +
            "  \"password\" : \"pwValue\",\n" +
            "  \"meterNumber\" : \"meterNumber1233445\",\n" +
            "  \"accountNumber\" : \"accountNumber6789\",\n" +
            "  \"key\" : \"keyValue\"\n" +
            "}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {};
        Map<String, String> result = objectMapper.readValue(testDeserStr, typeRef);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

and received the output:

```
{password=pwValue, meterNumber=meterNumber1233445, accountNumber=accountNumber6789, key=keyValue}
```

which is a valid result of `toString()` method of `HashMap<String, String>` base on your original input.

Comment: thanks for testing it and replying; I finally got it to work; the difference was I was using a mocked objectMapper instead of the one created locally in this method; still don't know why that mocked one doesn't work, but that was it

Comment: @user26270 if you mock `ObjectMapper` with Mockito or similar mocking libraries, you will never get a true parsing: any method invocation of mocked class will return either `null` or the result you configure this method to return (in Mockito you would use `Mockito.when` to configure methods behavior)